# Vimscript: Can list creation be split over multiple lines?

Tags: vim

Does Vimscript allow for this notation style when creating a list?

```
let mylist = [
               "a",
               "b",
               "c"
             ]
```

Or is it confined to one-liners (`let mylist = [ "a", "b", "c" ]`)?
I'm writing a list that I can easily foresee adding elements to later.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can make a statement in vimscript span multiple lines by adding a `\` to the start of the next line

```
let mylist = [
  \"a",
  \"b",
  \"c",
  \]
```

This is covered in `:help line-continuation` ([doc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#line-continuation))

Comment: This works, but with limitations.  This will work in `.vimrc` and sourced `whatever.vim` scripts, but if these newlines and backslashes are run from a vim register, it will vim will puke with `E697: Missing end of List ']'`. I guess the moral of the story is vim registers somehow corrupt this kind of line continuation.

Comment: Is it possible to have comments after each , on each line?